# TabBarController.selectedView is null

Tags: ios

I have a TabBarController inside a SplitViewController in the detail section.

In the TabBarController's class I want to get a reference to the currently presented view in the TabController.

I have tried `self.selectedViewController` and `self.presentedViewController` and these are both null. I'm testing them in `viewDidLoad` for the TabBarController.

Is this the correct place? Am I calling them to early (ie before the view for the selected tab is set?)

Thanks

james

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use presentedViewController in this case. That is for getting a reference to a view controller that you have presented modally - selectedViewController is what you need.

Yes, viewDidLoad would be the wrong place to get a reference to the selected view controller, as it doesn't exist yet.

You create a tab bar controller in two steps:

First, you create your instance. This is the point when alloc, init, and your view life cycle methods are going to be called.

Second, you set the array of view controllers.

If you're trying to get a reference in viewDidLoad, you're trying to get a reference at the first step, before you've assigned the tab bar controller an array of view controllers.

What you should do is create a custom method to kick things off in your tab bar controller, which you'll call from the class that creates the tab bar controller. Just make sure you invoke that method after you've assigned the array of view controllers to your tab bar controller. Then you'll be able to get a valid reference using selectedViewController, within your custom method.

Edit: For storyboards, move the code to viewDidAppear - viewDidLoad is called before the view is visible, and therefore no view controller is selected yet. In viewDidAppear, use selectedViewController (not presentedViewController) and it will contain a valid reference at that point.

Comment: should i be using prepare for segue method here? it doesnt sound right as the tab controller wont be setup at this point - or will it?

as i'm setting up everything via a storyboard i'm not explicitly assigning the array of view controllers.

Comment: if i added a method say (UIViewController *)getSelectedView to my tab controller class i could call that, but still wont't know at which point i should call it

Comment: I see, I didn't realise you we're using storyboards. In that case, you need to move the code to viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad - viewDidLoad is called before the view is visible, and therefore no view controller is selected yet. Again, make sure you use selectedViewController and not presentedViewController and as long as you do so from viewDidAppear, it should contain a valid reference.

Comment: thanks peter - that has done the trick - I tried viewWILLAppear, but that was still too early. got it wrokring now. All for the joy of handling the button to show the master view when the split view hides it!